# Bootstrap tooltip shows overwrite col class

Tags: html, css

I want to show bootstrap tooltip which is in a col class, but I want it to show all content was written in, but col-md4 is too small to do so. So what I have to do to bootstrap tooltip show over col class?

[image]

Comment: provide a minimal code sample of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the popover-append-to-body='true' attribute to put the tooltip at the end of your HTML where you have better control over the z-order.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/